# Update The database using applets

Tags: java, oracle, applet, file-permissions, sql-grant

I have written a code in **JAVA** to search files from the system.User specifies the filename and extension on text input on applet window and on button click code establishes a connection to ***oracle database*** and searches the directory name from the database table.The code for searching works fine without applet and on using applet it detects an error which is

**"access denied(java.util.PropertyPermissionfile.encoding read)"**

How do i grant this applet the permission to read from database?

Comment: I don't think that the permissions you are missing are for the database but for the file system. Can you please put the whole exception stack trace and also perhaps some code?

Comment: The code has no error..Its compiled successfuuly..Only when i run the applet in browser user enters the filename and extension to be searchd and after clicking the submit button the code should display the file location as a message dialogue bt its giving the error that i told-**access denied(java.util.PropertyPermissionfile.encoding read)**.Also just to check if click is working i added a code to change panel colour,thats also working but i am not getting what to do for the earlier error..                                                          ---Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

An applet is only allowed to connect to server from where it was downloaded. Otherwise you need to sign the applet. Or use a proxy to connect to the database from the machine the applet came from.

- See also [How can I connect from an applet to a database on the server?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=12992)

Comment: Actually the oracle server is local..Then also do i need to use a proxy?           ------Thanks in advance

Comment: According to this older doc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame5.html it should be possible.